# Running OpenMapTilesServer on RHEL8 with Podman

Tags: podman

I have a problem trying to run OpenMapTilesServer on RedHat 8 with Podman.

This is my start script:

```
sudo podman run -d -v $(pwd):/data -p 8080:80 docker.io/klokantech/openmaptiles-server
```

The image pulls okay, and it appears to start okay.
I can execute

```
podman ps
```

and see the container. All looks okay. If I look at the log using

```
podman logs <containerID>
```

I do not see anything that I consider a problem, however when I try to hit the homepage
http://localhost:8080, then I get site not found errors.

I thought it may be a firewall issue, so I disabled the firewall, but the same results. I also confirmed by installing Tomcat and starting it to serve a couple of HTML pages. This all works without errors.

Is someone able to suggest some further debugging I can do to get this going? thanks ...

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this problem. If I copy and paste your command line, I end up with a running openmaptiles server and I can connect to it on `localhost:8080` without a problem. Are you certain you don't already have something running on port 8080 on your host?

Comment: That is encouraging and I truly appreciate your effort trying to help. I don't believe I have any other apps running. I also changed the exposed port to 8800 and get the same results.
One point I should have mentioned is that my RHEL8 is a Virtual Machine, running on vsphere.

Comment: I have since tried this same scenario but replaced RHEL8 with newly created CentOS8 virtual machine, and I get the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spun up a CentOS 8 VM to test this out, and running the `podman` command from your post did result in a failure. I spent a little time this morning trying to figure out what was going on.

Looking at the output of `podman run`, I can see the following error:

```
[root@localhost data]# podman run --name tiles -v /tmp/data:/data -p 8080:80 docker.io/klokantech/openmaptiles-server
[...]
2019-11-05 12:29:26,812 INFO exited: wizard (exit status 1; not expected)
```

If I `podman exec` into the container, I can manually run the `wizard` command and see more detailed logs.  First, we need to figure out where the `wizard` command lives.  Since the container is using `supervisord` as a process supervisor, that means we probably need to look in `/etc/supervisor` for details:

```
[root@localhost ~]# podman exec -it tiles bash
root@de362646e453:/etc/supervisor# cd /etc/supervisor/
root@de362646e453:/etc/supervisor# ls
conf.d  supervisord.conf
root@de362646e453:/etc/supervisor# cd conf.d/
root@de362646e453:/etc/supervisor/conf.d# ls
openmaptiles.conf
root@de362646e453:/etc/supervisor/conf.d# cat openmaptiles.conf
[program:wizard]
command=/bin/bash -c "cd /usr/local/src && node wizard"
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
autostart=true
autorestart=false
startsecs=0
```

The key information is the `command` line in the `openmaptiles.conf` file. Let's try running the same command by hand:

```
root@de362646e453:/# cd /usr/local/src/
root@de362646e453:/usr/local/src# node wizard
Starting OpenMapTiles Map Server (action: run)
fs.js:961
  return binding.readdir(pathModule._makeLong(path), options.encoding);
                 ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/data'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:961:18)
    at Wizard.init (/usr/local/src/wizard/src/main.js:928:19)
    at new Wizard (/usr/local/src/wizard/src/main.js:119:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/src/wizard/src/main.js:1270:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
```

We're getting a "permission denied" error on the `/data` directory. The permissions look okay:

```
root@de362646e453:/# ls -ld /data
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 6 Nov  5 12:08 /data
```

But we're not able to access it:

```
root@de362646e453:/# cd /data
root@de362646e453:/data# ls
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
```

If file permissions look okay but you're still unable to access something, that often means it's time to look at your selinux configuration.  RHEL (and CentOS) both default to having selinux enabled. This will prevent a container from accessing parts of your filesystem to which they have not been explicitly granted access.

First, on the host, let's verify that `selinux` is running in `enforcing` mode:

```
[root@localhost ~]# getenforce
Enforcing
```

It is (as expected). Let's put it into permissive mode and see if that solves our problem:

```
[root@localhost ~]# setenforce 0
```

And now inside the container let's try and access the `/data` directory again:

```
[root@localhost ~]# podman exec -it tiles bash
root@de362646e453:/# ls /data
root@de362646e453:/#
```

Great! No more errors. Let's try restarting the container:

```
[root@localhost data]# podman run --name tiles -v $(pwd):/data -p 8080:80 docker.io/klokantech/openmaptiles-server
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:298: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2019-11-05 12:37:18,493 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2019-11-05 12:37:18,493 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/openmaptiles.conf" during parsing
2019-11-05 12:37:18,498 INFO Creating socket tcp://localhost:8081
2019-11-05 12:37:18,500 INFO Closing socket tcp://localhost:8081
2019-11-05 12:37:18,510 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2019-11-05 12:37:18,511 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2019-11-05 12:37:18,511 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2019-11-05 12:37:19,514 INFO spawned: 'wizard' with pid 8
2019-11-05 12:37:19,516 INFO spawned: 'xvfb' with pid 9
Starting OpenMapTiles Map Server (action: run)
2019-11-05 12:37:19,954 INFO success: wizard entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
2019-11-05 12:37:19,954 INFO success: xvfb entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
Config file not found!
Starting installation...
Installation wizard started at http://:::80/
List of available downloads ready.
```

That looks like a successful startup, and indeed, I can now access the tiles server on host port `8080`.

---

Now we have a decision to make:

1. We can persistently disable selinux, or
2. We can update our selinux configuration to permit the access that is currently being denied.

I would normally suggest (2), but it looks like the default selinux policy in CentOS 8 has some stupid defaults that make the process harder (the audit log messages that would identify the problem are disabled), so let's go with (1):

1. Edit `/etc/selinux/config`.
2. Change `SELINUX=enforcing` to either `SELINUX=permissive` (permits access but selinux is still active and will log policy violations) or `SELINUX=disabled`.
3. Reboot to make sure the change sticks as expected.

With this change, my CentOS 8 VM is now able to run the tiles server without a problem.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. 
Based on your suggestions I successfully located the log file inside the container that showed the problem. I logged into the container using (as root)
```
podman exec -it <containerID>  /bin/bash
```
logfile located in the directory '/etc/log/supervisor/' which contains logs of the error. 
New command 
```
sudo podman run -d -v /home/username/Mapping:/data:ro,Z -p 8080:80/tcp  klokantech/openmaptiles-server
```
This is now operational. Can't thankyou enough for the help. :)

Comment: Here's a final PODMAN startup script I use. It maps both the data directory and the logs directory to the host. This is working under RHEL8 using PODMAN Ver1.0.4. gain - thanks for the help :) 

`
# recreate log file directories
mkdir -p /home/mapprov/Mapping/logs/apt
mkdir -p /home/mapprov/Mapping/logs/supervisor
mkdir -p /home/mapprov/Mapping/logs/nginx

# start OpenMapTiles-Server
sudo podman run  -d \
   -v /home/mapprov/Mapping:/data:ro,z \
   -v /home/mapprov/Mapping/logs:/var/log:rw,z \
   -p 8080:80/tcp  \
    klokantech/openmaptiles-server  
`

Answer (score 1):

This is a copy of the earlier post as it is unreadable without formatting. It shows the final start script I use to startup OpenMapTiles-Server container.

```
mkdir -p /home/mapprov/Mapping/logs/apt
mkdir -p /home/mapprov/Mapping/logs/supervisor
mkdir -p /home/mapprov/Mapping/logs/nginx


sudo podman run  -d \
         -v /home/mapprov/Mapping:/data:ro,z \
         -v /home/mapprov/Mapping/logs:/var/log:rw,z \
         -p 8080:80/tcp  \
          klokantech/openmaptiles-server
```